# How to get total page likes from facebook graph php api v2.6

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get total page likes using following method

```
$response = $fb->get('/{page_id}/insights/page_fans', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
         $data = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

but i am getting output like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fans",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 4950,
          "end_time": "2016-06-04T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 4951,
          "end_time": "2016-06-05T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 4954,
          "end_time": "2016-06-06T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Lifetime Total Likes",
      "description": "Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)",
      "id": "5440223423423f216075/insights/page_fans/lifetime"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/123/insights/page_fans?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAPZCXGPTTelvenkGYIwiZAbT4N26ZB97KwDvbi9TfoyvkeET8WLiSbVHS7k3FsQL5w5DFJK5mAus0XA1123TPaPBEpxhdUq123ZAx1r7B3wIVjJVjLk2jrVu1M8apfBndmz9FUviAzWRpR4vHRgBYcSxEn4JXcioASljYLwZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1464617613&until=1464876813",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/123/insights/page_fans?access_token=EAACEdEosDe0cBAPZCXG123PTTelvenkGYIwiZAbT4N26ZB97KwDvbi9TfoyvkeET8WLiSbVHS7k3FsQL5w5JK5mAus0XATPaPBEpxhdUqZAx1r7B3wIVjJVjLk2jrVu1M8apfBndmz9FUviAzWRpR4vHRgBYcSxEn4JXcioASljYLwZDZD&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1465136013&until=1465395213"
  }
}
```

but i need total likes of pages.how can we do this

old way using FQL - `select fan_count from page where page_id = page_id;` but i am trying using latest api v2.6

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; the values you are seeing in above output _are_ the total number of likes the page has(/had on these dates) - so what exactly do you want now …?

Comment: @CBroe i need total likes of pages.above output is related to the each date.i dont want to calculate based on dates.i need total page likes which is showing on facebook page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [from comments] i need total page likes which is showing on facebook page

Well then you should not have been using the `insights` edge to begin with, but just

```
/page-id?fields=fan_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get  the total page likes using

```
/page_id?fields=new_like_count
```

if you want to get the page's post likes using

```
/page_id?fields=posts{likes.summary(true)}
```